# measuring the time between two PHP form submissions

Tags: javascript, php, python, html, json

I am attempting to measure the period of time from when a user submits a PHP form to when they submit again. The form's action is the same page so effectively it's just a refresh. Moreover, the user may input the same data again. I need it so that it begins counting before the page refreshes as the result must be as accurate as possible. I have already tried a number of methods but none of which resulted in any success. I have simplified the following code:

**HTML Form**

```
<form method="GET" action="index.php">
<input id="motion_image" type="image" value="1" name="x" src="img/btn1.png">
<input id="motion_image" type="image" value="2" name="x" src="img/btn2.png">
</form>
```

Ultimately, I need to have a PHP or JavaScript variable of how long it took a user to press either one of these two buttons to when they again press either one of them. It is important that the counter begins before the refresh as the variable needs to be as accurate as possible. Furthermore, it needs to be responsive so that after say 5 seconds it triggers an event (e.g. a JavaScript alert). I did not feel it was necessary to include my previous attempts as they were all unsuccessful and I believe there is probably a better way. I have full access to the server the site is being hosted on so running a python sub script and exchanging variables using JSON or any other similar solutions are entirely possible.

Apologies for any mistakes and my general lack of stack overflow skills :)

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to a database, because you could save each submit in the database and compare them. You could also use the Html 5 localStorage (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to store every times you submit your form and compare each submit.

Comment: you want to misure submissions of  single user, or multiple user from different location and machines?

Comment: @NicolòCozzani just a single user Furthermore, I do have access to MySQL however such a method would be very inaccurate when trying to have a responsive result. The only way that I can see achieving this would be a loop of DB queries which would effectively freeze the site

Comment: Sorry but the last part of my previous comment was in reference to what you mentioned @Nicolas

Comment: Then use the localStorage, It's a easy way to keep simple information client side.

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks - Local Storage looks promising :) However, is there a better way to structure a JS timer than using "setInterval(counter++, 1000);" Sorry if there is something wrong with my syntax btw. I am trying to respond as quick as possible

Comment: If you are trying to keep time between send, i would suggest saving the timestamp in the localstorage and then compare the current one with the last one saved. I don't see why you need a timer for that.

Comment: @Nicolas Due to the nature of the project this is for it needs to be responsive and say check at least every half a second

Comment: If you need to check something every second then a recommand looking into socket technology, It allows you to have a real time connection, this way you are notifed immediately when a change occured. Take a look at [socket.io](http://socket.io/) it might be a good way to improve your project

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas :) From just having a brief look, using socket appears to be the best method - thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into the use of localStorage with JS I was able to find an accurate solution. I simplified my code for others who may face the same or a similar issue. Thanks for all those who helped :)

**HTML**

```
<form method="GET" action="index.php">
<input id="motion_image" type="image" value="1" name="x" src="img/btn1.png" onclick="return processInput(1)">
<input id="motion_image" type="image" value="2" name="x" src="img/btn2.png" onclick="return processInput(2)">
<input id="motion_image" type="image" value="3" name="x" src="img/btn2.png" onclick="return processInput(3)">
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function processInput(x) {
    localStorage.eventType = x;
    checkEventType();
}

function checkEventType() {
    if (Number(localStorage.eventType) == 1) {
        runningInterval = setInterval(function() {
            localStorage.counter = Number(localStorage.counter) + 1;
        }, 10);
    } else if (Number(localStorage.eventType) == 2) {
        runningInterval = setInterval(function() {
            localStorage.counter = Number(localStorage.counter) - 1;
        }, 10);
    } else if (Number(localStorage.eventType) == 3) {
        window.alert("Your counter is at " + localStorage.counter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not get the date for each form submit? then compare those dates? You can save it to your database, too. I hope you get some idea. (sorry, I should have put this in the comment, but I still can't)

Comment: Yeah i tried that earlier successfully however the counter needs to be responsive so that say it reaches 5 seconds it triggers an event - sorry I'll update my question now

Comment: I dont really quite understand your question, but, as far as I understand, you may want to: 1. get time of first user form submit. 2. get time of user's 2nd submit. 3. wait for 5 seconds then do something like alert? you can use setTimeout method https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Sorry I'll try and put my code into better context - I am trying to measure the time that a motor is running as to track it's location. I can't just trigger a function after 5 "units of distance" (seconds for example)  as due to the nature of the project at some point it could be at negative 1 "unit" and so the event would trigger at 4 which is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

if you can trust user's system time :

when user clicks the button get the user's system time with javascript and send it to server;

at server save the time somewhere ... like session or db;

when user clicked the button for second time -> do those steps again;

and after all you can compare those times together;

//

with js you can send each period of times that user spend's on page too.
for that whenever page loaded set the system time in some variable, and when user clicked the buttons get the time again and send both to server to get the exact spend time;

Comment: Thanks but the timer has to be responsive and be updated in real time. I believe Nicolas' recommendation to use socket technologies is most relevant but if you can think of any better alternatives they would be much appreciated :)